# How to open the log `global_step/sec` like `tf.estimator.Estimator` using MonitoredTrainingSession?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I meet a small probelms but I don't how to deal with it.

When I use the `tf.estimator.Estimator`, it will log two line each step like:

```
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 1110.33
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.00026583532, step = 9376 (0.090 sec)
```

But when I use the `tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession` alone with `LoggingTensorHook`, there's only one line each step without the info anbout `global_step/sec`.

```
INFO:tensorflow:step = 131, loss = 0.11608909, acc = 0.955 (0.282 sec)
```

So I want to know how to open the log of `global_step/sec`

I find the info `global_step/sec` seems be controled bt the arg `log_step_count_steps`, but I have set it.

In addition, I also want to know the meaning of `global_step/sec`, of which the annotation is "The frequency, in number of global steps, that the global step/sec is logged." from `MonitoredTrainingSession`

Answer (score 1):

OK, I find the question. The reason is that the arg `log_every_steps` of `tf.train.LoggingTensorHook` not match the `log_step_count_steps` of `MonitoredTrainingSession`.

Note, the two args must be same, if different, such 5 and 10, the `global_step/sec` will be one low and one high which lead to the graph of `global_step/sec` no meaning.

If someone know the meaning of `global_step/sec`, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

global_step/sec: A performance indicator showing how many batches (gradient
  updates) we processed per second as the model trains.